# What does conf/ subdirectory in the jdk contents imply and how to edit it?

Tags: java, configuration

I am going through java SE [documentation]([https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk20-readme-downloads.html#:~:text=man/index.html-,Configuration%20files,-(In%20the)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk20-readme-downloads.html#:%7E:text=man/index.html-,Configuration%20files,-(In%20the)) and I see that under contents of JDK we have configuration Files which are stored at conf/ subdirectory. Can anyone explain me what are the use cases where we may need to edit the contents of this subdirectory ?

I tried to go through the contents of this subdirectory and I also looked online and was not able to find any explainer on this subdirectory.

Comment: _"What does conf/ suydirectory in the jdk contents imply"_ It implies nothing, it stores configuration files. _"how to edit it"_ You edit configuration files with a text editor. The additional question you pose in your question body is far too broad and unspecific. (And really, if you have to ask why you would change it, you probably have no need to change it.)